# multiple select take ages with snowflake

Tags: join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have a table with 6M rows and it seems my query take ages.
I try to calculate values for 2 rolling months.

**Input:**

| Period | ID | Tag | Name | Program | Total Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-06-01 | ID1 | X | User1 | Program 1 | 438 |
| 2020-12-01 | ID2 | A | User2 | Program 2 | 118 |
| 2020-12-01 | ID3 | X | User3 | Program 3 | 380 |

**Wanted output:**

| Period | ID | Tag | Name | Program | Total Cost | Period M-1 | Total Cost M-1 | Period M-2 | Total Cost M-2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-06-01 | ID1 | X | User1 | Program 1 | 438 | 2017-05-01 | 372 | 2017-04-01 | 340 |
| 2020-12-01 | ID2 | A | User2 | Program 2 | 118 | 2020-11-01 | 103 | 2020-10-01 | 98 |
| 2020-12-01 | ID3 | X | User3 | Program 3 | 380 | 2020-11-01 | 362 | 2020-10-01 | 334 |

Where am i wrong ? The below query is very slow.

```
WITH month_M AS  (
SELECT "Period","ID","Tag","Name","Program","Cost USD",
DATEADD(MONTH, -1, "Period" ) AS  "Period M-1 ",
DATEADD(MONTH, -2, "Period" ) AS  "Period M-2"
FROM "ARROWSPHERE_PROD_DB"."PBI_SCH"."Revenue_Dashboard"
), month_M1 AS (
SELECT "Period","ID","Tag","Name","Program","Cost USD"
FROM "ARROWSPHERE_PROD_DB"."PBI_SCH"."Revenue_Dashboard"
), month_M2 AS (
SELECT "Period","ID","Tag","Name","Program","Cost USD"
FROM "ARROWSPHERE_PROD_DB"."PBI_SCH"."Revenue_Dashboard"
)
SELECT M."Period",M."ID",M."Tag",M."Name",M."Program",M."Cost USD",
M."Period M-1 ",M1."Cost USD" AS "Total Cost M-1",M."Period M-2",M2."Cost USD" AS "Total Cost M-2"
FROM month_M AS M,month_M1 AS M1, month_M2 AS M2
WHERE M."Period M-1 "=M1."Period" AND M."Period M-2"=M2."Period"
  AND M."ID"=M1."ID" AND M."ID"=M2."ID"
  AND M."Tag"=M1."Tag" AND M."Tag"=M2."Tag"
  AND M."Name"=M1."Name" AND M."Name"=M2."Name"
  AND M."Program"=M1."Program" AND M."Program"=M2."Program"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by using a Window Function like LAG, and reducing drastically your SQL code complexity and the execution plan that will perform the operation, which I guess will require one single table scan only (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_TEST (
    Period  TIMESTAMP,
    ID      VARCHAR,
    Tag     VARCHAR,
    Name    VARCHAR,
    Program VARCHAR,
    TotalCost NUMERIC  
);

INSERT INTO TMP_TEST 
VALUES 
('2020-10-01',  'ID2',  'A', 'User2',   'Program 2',    98),
('2020-11-01',  'ID2',  'A', 'User2',   'Program 2',    103),
('2020-12-01',  'ID2',  'A', 'User2',   'Program 2',    118),
('2020-10-01',  'ID3',  'X', 'User3',   'Program 3',    334),
('2020-11-01',  'ID3',  'X', 'User3',   'Program 3',    362),
('2020-12-01',  'ID3',  'X', 'User3',   'Program 3',    380);


SELECT * , 
  DATEADD(MONTH, -1, Period) AS "Period M-1", 
  LAG(TotalCost, 1, 0) over (PARTITION BY Id, Tag, Name ORDER BY Period) AS "TotalCost M-2",
  DATEADD(MONTH, -2, Period) AS "Period M-2", 
  LAG(TotalCost, 2, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY Id, Tag, Name ORDER BY Period) AS "TotalCost M-1"
FROM TMP_TEST
ORDER BY Id, Tag, Name, Period;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is valid SQL so it's not "wrong" but since there are no predicates Snowflake must do a full table scan of 6e8 records, do processing and return about as many rows ...which is a lot of work to do.

If you can't just temporarily use a bigger warehouse, then you will have to dig into the Query Profile to find the bottleneck by clicking the query_id and then the "Profile" tab from the Worksheet UI.

First look at the Profile Overview and look at the breakdown of Remote IO to Processing.

You can reduce Remote IO by selecting fewer columns (if possible) or by using a predicate (like 1 year at a time, or users that start with X, or something... you may have to experiment.)  You can click on a step to see how much was able to be pruned.

You can reduce processing by doing less :) which won't be easy but you could try a left join (example below) or a window query.

```
WITH rev_dash as (select $1 "Period", $2 "ID", $3 "Tag", $4 "Name", $5 "Program", $6 "Cost USD" from values 
('2017-06-01', 'ID1', 'X', 'User1', 'Program 1', '438'),
('2020-12-01', 'ID2', 'A', 'User2', 'Program 2', '118'),
('2020-12-01', 'ID3', 'X', 'User3', 'Program 3', '380'),
('2017-05-01', 'ID1', 'X', 'User1', 'Program 1', '438'),
('2020-11-01', 'ID2', 'A', 'User2', 'Program 2', '118'),
('2020-11-01', 'ID3', 'X', 'User3', 'Program 3', '380'),
('2017-04-01', 'ID1', 'X', 'User1', 'Program 1', '438'),
('2020-10-01', 'ID2', 'A', 'User2', 'Program 2', '118'),
('2020-10-01', 'ID3', 'X', 'User3', 'Program 3', '380')
)
, month_M AS  (
SELECT "Period","ID","Tag","Name","Program","Cost USD",
DATEADD(MONTH, -1, "Period" ) AS  "Period M-1 ",
DATEADD(MONTH, -2, "Period" ) AS  "Period M-2"
FROM rev_dash
), month_M1 AS (
SELECT "Period","ID","Tag","Name","Program","Cost USD"
FROM rev_dash
), month_M2 AS (
SELECT "Period","ID","Tag","Name","Program","Cost USD"
FROM rev_dash
)
SELECT M."Period",M."ID",M."Tag",M."Name",M."Program",M."Cost USD", M."Period M-1 ",M1."Cost USD" AS "Total Cost M-1",M."Period M-2",M2."Cost USD" AS "Total Cost M-2"
FROM month_M AS M left join month_M1 AS M1 left join month_M2 AS M2
on M."Period M-1 "=M1."Period" AND M."Period M-2"=M2."Period"
  AND M."ID"=M1."ID" AND M."ID"=M2."ID"
  AND M."Tag"=M1."Tag" AND M."Tag"=M2."Tag"
  AND M."Name"=M1."Name" AND M."Name"=M2."Name"
  AND M."Program"=M1."Program" AND M."Program"=M2."Program"
where "Total Cost M-2" is not null;
```